# How to install opencv3 in anaconda for MAC OSX64?

Tags: anaconda, opencv3.0

I am trying to install opencv3 using Anaconda in my Mac using the following command

```
conda install -c menpo opencv3=3.2.0
```

But I am getting the following error

```
PackageNotFoundError: Package missing in current osx-64 channels:- opencv3 3.2.0*
```

Please help.

Comment: Have you found any solution to that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that Menpo (the package owner) doesn't have an opencv3 package for your python version; by the way, which is?, and OS.
See the different versions of opencv3 from different package owners in [Anaconda packages for opencv3](https://anaconda.org/search?q=platform%3Aosx-64%20opencv3).

Given that your question is a few weeks old, I guess you have the latest Python from Anaconda (3.6.x). As of now, there is an [opencv3 3.2 package for Python 3.6 mac osx from pluraldatum](https://anaconda.org/pluraldatum/opencv3), but for that it seems you need to install first the Intel TBB library.

There is another [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41873941/cant-install-opencv3-on-anaconda3-python3-6-on-macos) and people also asked about that in [Menpo's github repo](https://github.com/menpo/conda-opencv3/issues).