# Trouble installing opencv3 with anaconda python 3.6 (on mac)

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, anaconda

I have successfully installed anaconda with python3.6.1 on my mac. I followed the instruction from the internet:
first enter this on terminal:
conda create -n venv_demo python=3.6.1
then activate:
source activate venv_demo

However, when I tried to install openv3
I either tried the cmd line

conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/menpo opencv3

or

conda install -c menpo opencv3

it gave me the error as following:
[error showing on terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exKro.png)

Could someone tell me how to fix it? Do I need to remove python 2.7? Now I have installed python 3.6.1 and have 2 versions on my mac. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't install OpenCV3 on Anaconda3 python3.6 on macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41873941/cant-install-opencv3-on-anaconda3-python3-6-on-macos)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [list of conda installers for OpenCV](https://anaconda.org/menpo/opencv3/files) in under the menpo package on Anaconda's package list:

> osx-64/opencv3-3.1.0-py27_0.tar.bz2
>   osx-64/opencv3-3.1.0-py34_0.tar.bz2
>   osx-64/opencv3-3.1.0-py35_0.tar.bz2
>   linux-64/opencv3-3.1.0-py35_0.tar.bz2
>   linux-64/opencv3-3.1.0-py27_0.tar.bz2
>   linux-64/opencv3-3.1.0-py36_0.tar.bz2
>   linux-64/opencv3-3.1.0-py34_0.tar.bz2
>   linux-64/opencv3-3.2.0-np111py35_0.tar.bz2
>   linux-64/opencv3-3.2.0-np111py34_0.tar.bz2
>   linux-64/opencv3-3.2.0-np111py27_0.tar.bz2
>   win-32/opencv3-3.1.0-py27_0.tar.bz2
>   win-64/opencv3-3.1.0-py35_0.tar.bz2
>   win-32/opencv3-3.1.0-py35_0.tar.bz2
>   win-64/opencv3-3.1.0-py34_0.tar.bz2
>   win-32/opencv3-3.1.0-py34_0.tar.bz2
>   win-64/opencv3-3.1.0-py27_0.tar.bz2

Notice the Python versions listed in each installer. For macOS, the newest menpo installer is OpenCV 3.1.0 and works on Python 3.5. So if you want to use the menpo installer, simply create a new environment with Python 3.5, activate, and then install:

```
conda create -n <opencv virtual env> python=3.5
source activate <opencv virtual env>
conda install -c menpo opencv3
```

Otherwise if you want to use Python 3.6 (which *is* a really great Python release), you'll need to build from source. See the great answer from this Stack Overflow question: [Can't install OpenCV3 on Anaconda3 python3.6 on macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41873941/cant-install-opencv3-on-anaconda3-python3-6-on-macos?rq=1).